# NSPopUpButtonCell won't Pop Up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a table whose `NSTableColumns` are created dynamically in code. I need to add an `NSPopUpButtonCell` to one of these columns programatically. I do so with the following code:

```
NSPopUpButtonCell *dataCell = [[[NSPopUpButtonCell alloc] initTextCell:@"" pullsDown:NO] autorelease];
[dataCell setBordered:NO];
[dataCell insertItemWithTitle:@"[TEMP]" atIndex:0];
[myNewTableColumn setDataCell:dataCell];
```

The pop up button cell appears in the table fine, but when I click on it, nothing happens. I've tried calling `[dataCell setEditable:YES]` but when I do that, the cell edits with a field editor like an `NSTextFieldCell`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! I forgot that the table I was using was an `NSTableView` subclass that overrode the `- mouseDown:` method to do something else. As such, I ended up never sending the proper message to the pop up cell to actually get it to pop up.

A quick call to `[super mouseDown:theEvent]` has everything working as expected.